# Запустить джава файл с помощью с++

Tags: java, c++, c

Можно ли скомпилированный бинарный java-файл запустить с помощью С++? Без `system`!

Comment: все зависит тогда от нужной операционной системы. Или вызовы CreateProcess/execv не подходят? Тогда похоже нужно писать свой интерпретатор байт кода.

Comment: Почему без `system`? Что конкретно вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Можно, в теории. Открыть файл и "скормить" содержимое виртуальной машине Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [JNI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) для запуска виртуальной машины из вашего кода:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void error(char* msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
    JavaVM *vm;
    JNIEnv *env;

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 1;

    // Запуск виртуальной машины
    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **) &env, &vm_args);
    if (res < 0) {
        error("Can't create JVM\n");
    }

    // Загрузка класса HelloWorld.class из текущего каталога
    jclass mainCls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "HelloWorld");
    if (mainCls == NULL) {
        error("HelloWorld class not found\n");
    }

    // Получение метода static void main(String[] args)
    jmethodID method = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, mainCls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if (method == NULL) {
        error("main() method not found\n");
    }

    // Создание строкового массива аргументов
    jclass strCls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
    jobjectArray args = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 0, strCls, NULL);
    if (args == NULL) {
        error("Out of memory\n");
    }

    // Вызов HelloWorld.main()
    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, mainCls, method, args);

    // Завершение работы виртуальной машины
    (*vm)->DestroyJavaVM(vm);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Приблизительно вот так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int rc;
    char *new_argv[] = {"java", "-jar", argv[1], NULL};

    // Аргумент команандной строки(имя файла jar) передаём интерпретатору java
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("введите команду: %s <Имя jar файла>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    rc =  execvp("java", new_argv);
    // Здесь мы не должны никогда оказаться
    printf("Ошибка при вызове exexvp\n");
}
```

Я запускаю свой MIB-браузер, расположенный в каталоге */usr/local/bin/mibbrowser/lib/* вот таким образом:

```
gcc main.c
./a.out /usr/local/bin/mibbrowser/lib/browser.jar
```