# Плагин на C++ который запускает код на Java

Tags: java, c++

Есть известная игра CS:GO в которой можно хостить свои сервера и добавлять на них плагины. Эти плагины пишутся на C++ ([plugin wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_plugins)), существует даже проект [SourceMod](https://www.sourcemod.net) на котором создали свой язык для написания плагинов. Мне интересно, можно ли как-то обойти систему и заставить игру запускать и выполнять java код? К примеру сделать также как и в sourcemod: создать метод с командами EventHandler которая указывает нужные ивенты в игре и вызывает нужный метод получив эти ивенты...
Буду благодарен за ответ.

Обьясню про ивенты и EventHandler: в sourcemod есть метод (к примеру OnPluginStart) в которые обычно кладут команды EventHandler где пишут какой event нужно поймать и какой метод вызвать если поймал...

Comment: Можно, и java, и javascript. Но зачем?

Comment: @VTT как бы человек может и не знать плюсы, а знать только яву

Comment: @AntonSorokin если человек запустит jvm из плюсов, то и плагин на плюсах осилит =)

Comment: @AntonSorokin можно поподробнее? Как это сделать?

Comment: Я то откуда знаю, вы вон @VTT лучше спросите

Comment: @VTT подскажешь как это сделать?

Comment: Например взять cpprestsdk и форвардить все методы в плагине в RESTful микросервис написанный на java.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запустить джава файл с помощью с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/886443/204271)

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Ведь есть даже проект под названием SourcePython и кто-то писал варианты на JavaScript и C# побольше узнать можно тут hlmod.net. Но вот как это реализовывать это уже другой вопрос